# Are There any Benefits to a High Voltage Coil Pack?

Tags: ignition, ignition-coil

I'm considering replacing [the coil pack on my 98 mazda 626 GF 2L](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/43630?noredirect=1), and am looking at a [standard replacement at about $15](http://www.ebay.com/itm/89-03-Ford-Lincoln-Mercury-Mazda-New-Ignition-Coil-/191774246306?fits=Year%3A1998%7CMake%3AMazda%7CModel%3A626&hash=item2ca6a2c5a2:g:u5YAAOSwmmxW34Gv&vxp=mtr), a [standard replacement with 10 year warranty for about $21](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Ignition-Coil-Pack-for-Ford-Mazda-Lincoln-Mercury-Pickup-Truck-F150-Van-SUV-Car-/130944655897?fits=Year%3A1998%7CMake%3AMazda%7CModel%3A626&hash=item1e7ce8e219:g:qFgAAOSw%7EgRVzabZ&vxp=mtr), and [a "high output" VMS for about $50](http://www.ebay.com/itm/VMS-RACING-HIGH-OUTPUT-IGNITION-DIS-COIL-PACK-FORD-MUSTANG-ESCORT-CONTOUR-F150-/361458937508?fits=Year%3A1998%7CMake%3AMazda%7CModel%3A626&hash=item5428a1aea4:g:i4YAAOSwk1JWhB-7&vxp=mtr).

For the first two it's not that big a difference in price, but I'm wondering if there are concrete, measurable benefits to the "high output" coil pack?  It claims:

> They will directly connect to the factory connectors and deliver 15%-20% more spark energy for improved power and performance.
>
> Increased spark energy and voltage, help improve the combustion process of the fuel mixture to create an efficient burn. The result are quicker starts, improved idle, improved throttle response, cleaner plugs, cleaner emissions plus increased high rpm performance!
>
> SPECIFICATIONS:
> • Turns Ratio 85:1
> • Primary Resistance 0.55 ohms
> • Secondary Resistance 13.5K ohms
> • Inductance 4.0 mH
> • Spark duration (mS) 1100 uS
> • Peak Current 140 mA
> • Maximum Voltage 40,000 Volts

I've read annecdotal evidence that such claims are true, but is there a measurable scientific basis to such claims, i.e. hard evidence, not just anecdotal claims?

Comment: I've only seen equipment like that on racecars that had custom tunes. I'm not sure you would benefit on a stock road car

Comment: @cloudnyn3 - There are plenty of aftermarket coils out there including those from Accel and MSD. These aren't strictly for race cars, but those can probably benefit the most from them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go with the standard replacement (the warranty choice is left up to you). High output coils are used in modified engines that have higher combustion chamber pressures from either higher compression, boost, or a combination of both. Save your money, unless you plan to turbocharge the 626...